# How to change background color with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery, and I would like to change the color of my background using the input and jQuery.

Could someone give me the right approach, because I'm seriously challenged?

```
<div>
    <input type="color" id="input">
</div>


$(input).ready(function(){
    $("body").on {
    });   
});
```

Comment: First, you try - and fail if necessary, there's no shame in that - and then, if your attempts don't succeed, come back and ask us a specific question. What did you attempt? In what way did it fail? What errors were reported? Do you know how to look at errors in the developer console?

Comment: Okay, I'll try again after school and come back if I need.